# Post ID randomly printing on page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, id

I'm getting and looping through some custom post types, and have no idea why the post ID is printing to the page--I have been looking at this forever now! My code is:

```
$args=array('post_type'=>'content');
$content= new WP_Query($args);
if($content->have_posts() ){
        echo "<div id='list'>
        <table id='allcontent' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>

        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>TYPE</th>
            <th>SOURCE</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
        </tr>";
    while($content->have_posts() ){
        $content->the_post();

        $permalink = get_permalink($id);
        $src = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $key='_origin')[0];
        $date = the_date(get_the_ID());
        $type = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $key='_type')[0];
        $title = "<a href='$permalink'>".get_the_title(get_the_ID())."</a>";

        echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$title."</td>
                    <td>".$type."</td>
                    <td>".$src."</td>
                    <td>".$date."</td>
                </tr>";

    }



    echo "</table></div>";
}
```

The odd thing is that my ID is printing on the page right under the tag for

```
<div id="list">
```

and not even inside the table itself, which is particularly baffling.

If anyone is able to help I would appreciate it greatly!!

Comment: This part looks problematic:  `$date = the_date(get_the_ID());` Note that it doesn't return a value, only echos it, and has wrong [input](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/).

Comment: That fixed it!!! Wow, I wonder what about that made it print the ID outside of the table. Thank you so much!

Comment: You also have `get_permalink($id)` with `$id` not defined, so you may want to address that to resolve other issues.